# Digital Ocean App Crash: Potential memory issue?

Tags: memory, docker, crash, node.js, digital-ocean

I have a Linux-based docker container running on the DigitalOcean Apps platform. It's been stable for over a month - but it recently crashed. App logs show no indicators of code warnings or errors, leading me to believe there may be a lower level problem. With no other indicators to go off of, I reviewed the memory and cpu usage history.

**Chart History:**

View them here: [image]

1. Memory usage seems to cycle between approximately 40% to 80%, about
   5 to 8 times daily, with a sawtooth pattern (a gradual climb followed by a swift drop).
2. There has been a gradual increase in the average memory usage by around 10% over the past two weeks.

**Seeking Advice On:**

1. Are the sawtooth memory cycles likely normal garbage collection routines, or is it more likely that they are symptomatic of a deeper issue?
2. The steady rise in average memory usage: Is it significant enough to warrant deeper investigation? Or would a routine redeployment every two weeks be a reasonable practical workaround to keep the server running smoothly?

I would value any insights or suggestions from the community. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Beside the memory usage, do you have any indication of a problem?

Comment: @music2myear yes, the server crashed with no indication of code errors.

Comment: Your server crashed how many times. What indication do you have that the crash was related to memory? Can you make sure whatever prevented logs from being recorded has been fixed?

Comment: @music2myear It only crashed once. My code error/warning logs are streaming properly (to NewRelic) and there is no indication of a code error causing the crash. Lower-level logs are ephemeral and were not available after the restart. I have no indication that the crash was memory-related aside from analyzing my CPU/memory usage charts (provided by my host DigitalOcean) during the post-mortem.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to find anything by measuring the "pulse-rate"
of your computer. A crash in most cases is caused by software,
not by hardware.

If you wish to understand the crash :

- Examine the Event Viewer for errors from the time of
  the crash
- Look in `C:\Windows\Minidump` for `.dmp` files from the time of
  the crash and post them online for us to examine
- Examine the SMART attributes of the hard disk
- Run `chkdsk`
- Test Windows integrity by running the commands
  [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
  and then
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- Ensure Windows is fully updated.

Comment: I just noticed the "linux" tag on your post - am I going totally in the wrong direction?

Comment: yes, though I may be posting in the wrong place. My "server" is a linux docker container running in a virtualized hosting environment. I definitely should have included that detail.

Comment: Yes, definitely. Suspected hardware problems need to be examined on the host, which is what?